# Not selecting elements correctly with jquery show hide div containers

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

updated

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( document ).ready(function(){
    $("#the_submit_button").click(function(){
      e.preventDefault(); 
        if $("representativepassword") == "sales"
          $("protectivepanel").hide()
            $("secretpanel").show()
    });
  });
</script>
```

I am getting uncaught syntax error, unexpected identifier

---

Here is my embedded javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( document ).ready(function(){
    $("#the_submit_button").click(function(){
      e.preventDefault(); 
        if $("text") == "sales" <!--something here--> 
          $("protectivepanel").hide()
            $("secretpanel").show()
    });
  });
</script>
```

I have never used jquery before. I know it is selecting the_submit_button properly because I have tried modifying it will css.

this is my bootstrap form

```
<div class="container" id="protectivepanel">
  <form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="representativepassword">Representative's Password</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="representativepassword" placeholder=" Enter Password">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="the_submit_button">Submit</button>
  </form>
<div>
```

I have a huge container that I am hiding and revealing once the password is entered correctly.

currently the container looks like this

Secret stuff

I have tried

```
 ("input:sales"), ("representativepassword"), ("representativepassword)
```

syntax error? not selecting id properly?

Comment: In jquery $("text") is saying I am trying to select <text>. To select a class $('.className') for ID $('#ID')

Comment: i hope you realise, that this is majorly unsecure?

Comment: I know, we just want it to work for now.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery uses CSS Selectors:

```
$('div')
```

grabs all divs

```
$("#protectivepanel")
```

grabs element with protectivepanel as ID

```
$(".secretpanel").show()
```

grabs element with secretpanel in class

Answer (score 0):

Your selectors are not specifying ID.. `$("#representativepassword")`..

Use # to select by ID..

Here is a list of available selectors:

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple of problems here.

1. In `e.preventDefault()` you are referencing undefined variable `e`. Try adding parameter e to the anonymous function declaration handling the click event. For example: `$("#the_submit_button").click(function(e){`.
2. You are passing id values to jQuery, but omitting the "#" prefix that tells jQuery they are supposed to be IDs. For example, you need to change `$("protectivepanel")` to `$("3protectivepanel")`.
3. You are attempt to select the text input element by passing "text" to jQuery, but you should instead do this: `$("input[type=text]")`.
4. Once you have selected the text input element, you need to use the `val()` method to get its contents. So change `if $("text") == "sales"` to `if $("input[type=text]").val() === "sales"`.

Answer (score 0):

As the others said you need to specify the selectors for the elements if it's an ID , a class or an element with a type of like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#the_submit_button").click(function(e){ //you need to send the event to the function otherwise the submit will work as normal
      e.preventDefault();
        if($(":text") == "sales"){ //Search for an element of type text
          $("#protectivepanel").hide() //missing # for id
            $("#secretpanel").show() //missing # for id or . for class
         }
    });
  });
```